# Java ImageIO.write to classpath?

Tags: java, image, file-io, inputstream, javax.imageio

I am trying to use the `ImageIO` class to save an image and then get the resource using an input stream. My problem is that I keep getting a `NullPointerException` whenever I try to create the input stream. If I simply go and put an image file in the class path, it works. Here is my code:

```
ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("temp.png"));
InputStream imgIs = AptCap.class.getResourceAsStream("temp.png");
byte[] imgData = new byte[imgIs.available()]; // I get null here.
```

I have also tried specifying direct locations to files on the C drive for both of them, but I still get a null pointer exception. I would rather not do that anyway, but just keep it in the classpath (for purposes of multi OS support).

Comment: Change `new File("temp.png")` to `theByteArayOutputStream` and avoid the local disks altogether.

Comment: @AndrewThompson What is "theByteArayOutputStream". A variable I need to define or import... Or what.

Comment: Alternately, change `AptCap.class.getResourceAsStream("temp.png");` to something like `new FileInputStream("temp.png");`.  But I'd recommend the 1st approach.

Comment: See [`ByteArrayOutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html).  It would go something like:  `ByteArrayOutputStream theByteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); //..`

Comment: Ahh, ok thanks! The fileinputstream works!

Comment: ..I am disappointed you chose that way of solving the immediate problem.  Creating a file seems wasteful and unnecessary in this case.

Comment: Agree with @AndrewThompson . Please do try to keep it off the disk in this instance.

Comment: I have added a more complete form of the preferred way to go about this (*without* creating a `File` on disk).  Please consider using it instead.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I will go ahead and try that now.

Comment: ...any progress on that?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Sorry for not replying! It works great and seems to be faster also. Just wondering, does this save the data on the RAM for temporary storage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); // create OutputStream
ImageIO.write(image, "png", baos); // write to OS
InputStream imgIs = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()); // grab bytes from OS
//..
```